# How to use try catch in string reading case?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I have a string `s`. From that string, I want to extract `co-ordinates`.
For example

```
string s =  "(94 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE);"
```

From this string I want to extract 94,10,62 and 10.
For that I have written `Split()` which works perfectly.
For that:

I first split the string on the basis of `,`.

Then I again split the string on the basis of `*`.

Here is my code :

```
    std::vector<std::string> Split(std::string& s, char delim)
    {
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        std::string item;
        std::vector<std::string> elems;
        while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
            elems.push_back(item);
    
        return elems;
    }       
    
   vector<int> GetTheCoordinates(std::vector<std::string>& splittedString)
   {
         vector<int> vec;
         for (unsigned long j = 0; j < splittedString.size(); j++) 
        {
            std::vector<std::string> finalString = Split(splittedString[j], '*');
            int leftValue = stoi(finalString[0]); 
            vec.push_back(leftValue);
        }
     return vec;
}

 int main()
{   
    string str = "(94 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE);"
    std::string s = str.substr(1, str.size() - 3); // removing ( and ); from str
    std::vector<std::string> splittedString = Split(s, ',');
    std::vector<int> vec = GetTheCoordinates(splittedString);
}
```

Above code works and I get the co-ordinates.
Here question is :

1. I have assumed that string will contain `,` when I try to split on
   the basis of `,` and assumed that it will have `*` when I try to split
   on the basis of `*`. But what if both times, string will not have `,`
   and `*` but some other symbols. Then how to handle that case using
   `try-catch` ?
2. I have used `stoi(finalString[0]);` but what if
   string is not integer convertible. Then how to handle it using
   `try-catch` ?

Input :  string str = "(94 * SCALE & 10 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE);"

Output : line should have `,` not `&`.

Input string str = "(94 & SCALE , 10 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE);"

Output : line should have `*` not `&`

Comment: this is not a string: ***(94 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE)***

Comment: Sorry but now I updated the code.

Comment: do you know how to throw and catch exceptions? If not you should start with a 2-3 lines example that does only that

Comment: Why `try`-`catch`? If your split function is called with a string that doesn't contain `delim` it will return a `std::vector` with only one element. Checking for that condition is probably better than throwing and catching exceptions.

Comment: Is there a need that there always 4 coordinates or could it be more or less? Depending on that it is important how to answer your first question. Also is there a need that it is always called "SCALE" after the `*`?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Sometime it will have 4 co-ordinates some times more than that. SCALE will always be there after `*`.  But it is no use for me. I am not going to read that `SCALE`.

Comment: please include example input and expected output in the question.

Comment: @churill  Currently there are 3  `,` and 4 `*` but what if it will contains 2 `,` and 2 `*`  ?

Comment: what if? its not quite clear. What your current code does you can try by supplying such input. What you want to happen instead you have to tell us

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  I am getting correct output. I just want to know, how to use `try-catch` if there are different symbols than I expected ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  I am writing a parser.  In that I am going to read file which will have inputs like  string str  line by line. So mistakenly if one of the line contains wrong info then my code should handle that.

Comment: i already asked, do you know how to throw and catch an exception in general? Did you try to add a try-catch to catch the exception potentially thrown by `stoi` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know `try-catch` but here I am not understanding how to use that. Means  `try {   if(symbols other than ,) } catch { "Wrong symbols" } `

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  How to write logic for `symbols other than , ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you want.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "(94 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 10 * SCALE);";
    s = s.substr(1);

    std::vector<std::string> container;
    boost::split(container, s, boost::is_any_of("*,"));

    // want to extract
    std::vector<int> vals;
    for (auto item : container) {
        try {
            int val = std::stoi(item.c_str());
            vals.push_back(val);
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument const& ex) {
            std::cout << "std::invalid_argument::what(): " << ex.what() << '\n';
        }
        catch (std::out_of_range const& ex) {
            std::cout << "std::out_of_range::what(): " << ex.what() << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nwant to extract:\n";
    for (auto val : vals) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
std::invalid_argument::what(): invalid stoi argument
std::invalid_argument::what(): invalid stoi argument
std::invalid_argument::what(): invalid stoi argument
std::invalid_argument::what(): invalid stoi argument

want to extract:
94
10
62
10
```